# Upon querying a database, delete an item from a list obtained via getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, sqlalchemy, flask

I have a list of items obtained upon querying a database. Result of the query is treated with `jsonify`and finally obtained via `getJson`, by doing the following:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/appointments/', function(data) {
        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i in data.appts) {
            output+="<li>" + data.appts[i].labo + "</li>"
        }
        output+="</ul>";
        $("#result").html(output)                  
    return false;
  });
});
```

So far so good...

Now I need to give the possibility to delete each of the above listed items, by calling (for example ) the following `Flask`function:

```
@app.route('/appointments/<int:appointment_id>/delete/', methods=['DELETE'])
def appointment_delete(appointment_id):
    appt = db.session.query(Appointment).get(appointment_id)
    db.session.delete(appt)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'status': 'OK'})
```

Unfortunately I have no clue on how it's possible to bridge these two pieces of code. Since I've being struggling on that for a while, I would appreciate any help that will allow me to get out of the mud... Thanks a lot.!

**EDIT** according to @dcodesmith's comment

The `getJSON` response:

```
{
   "appts":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "day":"Mardi",
         "labo":"l1",
         "modified":[
            "21/01/2014"
         ],
         "groups":"5",
         "plage_h":"10h00",
         "sem":"5",
         "start":[
            "28/01/2014"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "day":"Vendredi",
         "labo":"l1",
         "modified":[
            "22/01/2014"
         ],
         "groups":"5",
         "plage_h":"10h00",
         "sem":"5",
         "start":[
            "31/01/2014"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Could you post the response returned from the `$.getJSON` function. I just want to see if it has the each `appts` unique id in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Changes required

- Firstly, edit your output HTML to include an anchor tag which should have a data-id attribute with the appts id assigned to it.
- Create a click event on the anchor tag in your list of appts

### Code

```
$(function() {

    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/appointments/', function(data) {
        var output = "<ul>";
        for (var i in data.appts) {
            var appt = data.appts[i];
            output += "<li>" + appt.labo + "<a href='#' class='delete' data-id=" + appt.id + ">delete</a></li>"
        }
        output+="</ul>";
        $("#result").html(output)                  
        return false;
    });


    $(document).on('click', 'a.delete', deleteAppt);

    function deleteAppt(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            id = $this.data('id'),
            url = "/appointments/" + id + "/delete/";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id: id}
        })
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            if (data.status === 'OK'){
            // if successful remove deleted row
                $this.parent('li').remove();
            }
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //log your error here, if any is caught. This will be very helpful for debugging
        })
    }
});
```

Note: I know nothing about Flask, but this should work *Ceteris Paribus*

Comment: amazing..that works: just need to replace `'POST'` with `'DELETE'` in the `Ajax`function